# Стоит ли беспокоиться о пользователях со странными именами?

Tags: обсуждение, спам

Периодически вижу участников с именами, выглядящими как спам - типа "ЗАРАБОТОК В ИНТЕРНЕТЕ" или "[Квартиры Петербург](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/333838/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3)". Проверял их профили, вопросы, ответы и комментарии, никаких признаков рекламы не заметил. Что это? Людские причуды или признаки взлома?

Comment: @Kromster "ЗАРАБОТОК В ИНТЕРНЕТЕ" переименовался через день, и я уже не помню в кого, а "[Квартиры Петербург](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/333838/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3)" прямо сейчас висит в списке "Недавно полученные знаки".

Comment: Считаю, что Sergey Gornostaev - очень странное имя!

Comment: @yolosora подумываю переименоваться в Joy Casino.

Comment: Я бы выбрал имя "продам гараж" тогда :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Полагаю, дело в том, что аккаунт создавался через какую-либо стороннюю учетную запись, например, Google. И там пользователь указал имя, соответствующее его деятельности в этой системе, а при регистрацци не поменял.

Comment: Хммм. А это выглядит как ответ!

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev и от какого участника!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ это не тот [Маликов](https://stackoverflow.com/users/570689/%D0%94%D0%9C%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%99-%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%98%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%92) :)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev но вполне может быть, что тот самый, создавший аккаунт через какую-либо стороннюю учетную запись, например, Google.

Answer (score 15):

Пользователь вправе выбирать себе любое имя, не являющееся бранным или как-то иначе неуместным для публикации. Также участник вправе писать в профиле соответствующую информацию, в том числе приводить ссылки на сайты. Для новых пользователей, насколько я знаю, есть ограничение на публикацию ссылок, т.е. они не будут кликабельными как минимум. Участников со странными именами можно, конечно, взять на карандаш (может быть доработать SmokeDetector бота под такие профили), но пока явных нарушений нет - делать что-то особенное с такими аккаунтами не нужно.

Одно время на MSE (а может и по всей сети SE) создавались множественные аккаунты со ссылкой на какого-то автодилера внутри. Эти аккаунты прожили несколько дней (может даже недель), но потом их всё же уничтожили/обезличили. При этом проблема имела тогда действительно массовый характер.

Для единичных случаев, упомянутых вами, я бы рассматривал это именно под призмой "причуд", не нарушающих правил сайта или его работу.