# Волна участников без сообщений, но с рекламой в профиле. Что с ними делать и почему их стало так много?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, профиль-участника, спам

На мете было [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9066/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8) на счёт имён, которые похожи на рекламу. Но я немного про другое.

Открыл я знак [автобиограф](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer)... И нашёл огромное количество пользователей (25+), которые публикуют спам в своём профиле. Но сообщений у этих пользователей нет.

Их легко найти. У них в нике почти всегда есть слово "spam".

[image: вот они]

Есть ещё особые товарищи, которые признаются в том, что это они создают спам-аккаунты.

[обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5): что с ними делать? Да, у них нет сообщений, но спам в профилях тоже недопустим. Ведь тогда по слову "spam" можно будет прийти из гугла. И появятся ещё больше спамеров, которые будут спамить уже не в профилях...

Или этот товарищ сейчас спам-акки насоздавал, а потом приведёт их "в действие"? Как с этим потом справиться? Бан по IP не поможет, ибо есть vpn.

[предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5): может, сжечь учётки всех вышеперечисленных спамеров?

**Обновление:** оказывается, это не впервые. [Поднималось на MSE 6 лет назад](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303835/1346379).

Comment: Отличный ход! И ведь никто не догадается, что этот пост был написан с целью увеличения просмотров рекламируемых этими спам-аккаунтами товаров и услуг!

Comment: @Byb убрал список. Заменил на скрин.

Comment: Спам в профилях это точно не ново. Поищите по "Dubai" в пользователях, там есть и трехлетней давности. Но тот факт, что спамеры свои художества подписывают как спам, любопытен. Может они гуглом переводят с какого-нибудь хинди, и переводчик им не по делу вставляет слово "spam"?

Comment: Еще одно прошлое обсуждение: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2952/240512