# Почему у вопроса так много просмотров?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, показы

Сегодня был задан вот такой примечательный вопрос:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причём пока я писал сюда, количество просмотров на нём увеличилось ещё на 100 единиц. С чем это связано? Какой-то баг? Бывал ли он раньше? Или, может, это только у меня так показывается?

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что что-то не так?

Comment: Не стоит забывать и про [FHRC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/339911)

Comment: @Grundy несколько аномальное количество просмотров за такое время. Видимо, где-то ссылку запостили. Похоже, хвосты от олимпиады [Сириус](https://siriusolymp.ru/) тянутся. Завтра последний день :)

Comment: Кстати, уже почти 3k показов. Хм... А этот пост точно не для того, чтобы увеличить количество показов в вопросе? (*шутка*)

Comment: @Зонтик по-моему увеличить просмотры это хорошо ж, сайт оживить. Не все молодые программисты знают про ру, идут на англ.версию

Comment: @Dev18 увеличить просмотры оффтопика - не есть круто. К тому же здесь, на мете, есть только те, которые уже знают про ruSO)

Comment: @Зонтик в вопросе вопрос не про вопрос на мете, а основной сайт. и почему не есть круто ? чем больше наш ресурс будут знать молодые программисты тем лучше для базы

Comment: @Dev18 вы меня не поняли. Этот вопрос вызывает желание посмотреть другой вопрос (на основном сайте). На самом деле эта шутка - отсылка к [этой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13030/87#comment56289_13030).

Comment: аааааааааа, ок. вопрос на мете, зовет за вопросом на ру, и так это круговорот просмотров, но не новых программистов тк на мете все знающие основной. ну понятней теперь, но я не пошла. искать вопрос тратить время, ведь в вопросе ссылки то нема @Зонтик

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, всё дело в олимпиаде, проходящей на текущий момент:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прикольно) Хотя, конечно, вряд ли из-за одной только олимпиады столько школьников будет целенаправленно заходить на стек. Скорее всего, как вы сказали в комментарии, тут без ссылки на вопрос не обошлось. Наверно, куда-то в общий чат олимпиады скинул. В общем, спасибо за ответ) Теперь я знаю, как можно легко заработать медальку "знаменитый вопрос" xD

Comment: @Byb из поисковиков по тексту задачи вполне можно выйти, сейчас и в гугле, и в яндексе в первой десятке.